# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, scroll

Trying to get the page to scroll to an anchor and I'm getting this error.

Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Right now I have my JS like the following...

```
//scroll to section process page
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("div[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("li.menu-item-141 a").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('#philosophy-page');
});
```

Here is my HTML...

```
<div class="container">
<div name="philosophy-page" id="philosophy-page">
    <div class="philosophy-heading">
        <h1>Philosophy</h1>
    </div><!-- /.philosophy-heading -->
</div><!-- /#philosophy-page -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Any help would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

replace

```
scrollToAnchor('#philosophy-page');
```

by

```
scrollToAnchor('philosophy-page');
```

Remember you use the `name` to find the `a` element:

```
var aTag = $("div[name='"+ aid +"']");
```

jQuery cannot find an element named `#philosophy-page`

Comment: Yep this worked! Thank you!!!! I will mark as right answer... You can accept an answer in 11 minutes StackOverflow says currently

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Best scroll to I have found.
Found it on CSS Tricks:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 1):

Pass id without `#` as name does not `#` in it.

*Change*

```
 scrollToAnchor('#philosophy-page');
```

*To*

```
 scrollToAnchor('philosophy-page');
```